# Getting Maximum Speed with OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, api, openstreetmap, osmdroid

For a Android application that I am making, I am trying to to find the maximum speed for each road using the OpenStreetMap API (OSMdroid).

What is the best way to get the maximum speed from this API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: osmdroid is not "the OpenStreetMap API", it is just a collection of android tools for OSM.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK osmdroid just displays the raster map tiles that are offered by various providers. There is no real vector data, so you can't query.

What you can do instead:

- Use preprocessed map tiles that color the OSM maxspeed=* tag
- Use [OSMbonuspack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) as osmDroid addon to display own overlays. This need to be processed by your own, maybe using osmosis and export it as a suitable vectorformat like KML or geoJSON

So it depends on what you want to do in detail. Just vizualize or more like routing?